# What is Annotation in regards to Document Format Open Xml?

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I search this and get only one following line on msdn website - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.inkml.annotation_members(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.inkml.annotation_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) without any explanation:-

Get the first annotation object of the specified type from this PartContainer

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to know about what this Annotation is from the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/27/the-use-of-extension-methods-to-manage-open-xml-document-changes-in-powertools-for-open-xml.aspx

**Annotations are simply objects that can be attached to other objects.**

Answer (score 1):

Check out the extract from Open XML Specification:

> **17.13  Annotations**
>
> Within a WordprocessingML document, annotations refer to various types of supplementary markup which can  be stored inside or around a region of text within the document's contents.
> [Example: The types of  supplementary information stored within a
> document can include: comments, revisions, spelling and/or
> grammatical errors, bookmark information and optional editing
> permissions. end example]
>
> Within a document's contents, annotations
> are stored in one of three different methods:
>
> - Inline
> - Cross Structure
> - Properties
>
> These three forms are needed in order to
> maintain compatibility with both the legacy annotations functionality
> of current word processing applications and the requirements of an
> XML-based format (i.e. wellformedness of  the resulting XML markup).
> These three forms are referenced within the individual annotation
> types described  in the following sub clauses.

The whole section of `17.13` deals with `Annotations` and can be read from - http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm